# Python keeps crashing when I'm deploying with google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gcloud

I'm running a static server on google app engine. I have been able to deploy a couple of times, but now it keeps crashing and it says

**Python quit unexpectedly.**

You can find my log on this URL: https://gist.github.com/rickbrunstedt/39a949016ca8bae46bad07395175a3e5

the short version:

```
105 org.python.python               0x00000001000eef7a 

PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 458
106 org.python.python               0x000000010010614d Py_Main + 3101
107 org.python.python               0x0000000100000f14 0x100000000 + 3860

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007fff5fbf7600  rbx: 0x00000001025188a0  rcx: 0x0030000000000203  rdx: 0x00007fff5fbf7630
  rdi: 0x0000000104940830  rsi: 0x00000001025188a0  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbf75a0  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbf7568
   r8: 0x0000000000000001   r9: 0x0000000000000048  r10: 0x00000000ffffffff  r11: 0xffffffff846a3210
  r12: 0x00007ffff287bf68  r13: 0x00007fffe9dbc94a  r14: 0x00007fff5fbf7630  r15: 0x00000001025188b0
  rip: 0x00007fffe9dbc94e  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x0000000104940832

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100000fff +org.python.python (2.7.12 - 2.7.12) <C2055A43-D803-3CC5-FFF0-363A42F24F4E> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

I'm not sure where to begin to be able to solve this problem.

UPDATE:
I think the problem is in the python version on my machine.
This is the log message I have where I found the crash, but that doesn't tell me much about it, it's just too advanced for me.
https://gist.github.com/rickbrunstedt/b0c6524b427e7f1b57561205bdcf146f

I tried to install the newer version of python, but that didn't work either.

Comment: What's a "static server"? Are you using GAE for static files only? Where are you seeing the "Python quit unexpectedly." message? The log you provided does not have anything related. Are there any errors on [GAE Logs viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer)?

Comment: In the console program I found this log message which includes the crash: https://gist.github.com/rickbrunstedt/b0c6524b427e7f1b57561205bdcf146f
But that doesn't tell me much, that just to advanced for me to understand. But I think the problem is in my python something..

Comment: Please include the messages in your post, rather than as external links...

Comment: Try 1) Go to Activity Monitor, and Force Quit all the Python instances.  Then launch the app again.  2) Restart machine, then try again.

Comment: That didn't work :(

Comment: Have you tried the command line tools? For your info, look at the section that gives the error type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Comment: If we are talking about gcloud, then yes. I'm executing "gcloud app deploy". Haven't try the gui, thought that was used for other things. Where do I download that gui?

Comment: Hey @RickBrunstedt, could you post the logs which actually include the error message "Python quit unexpectedly"? It's not clear from the information posted what could be causing this. The logs posted are system-level process core-dumps which don't really give any useful information.

Comment: Additionally, the logs posted [here](https://gist.github.com/rickbrunstedt/39a949016ca8bae46bad07395175a3e5) don't seem to actually terminate, but cut off arbitrarily. Could you check whether a more full sample of *those* logs could not also be produced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this might be related to [a known issue in the gcloud Public Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=1168). Please follow the thread there for updates, and attempt the suggested workaround:

```
gcloud config set app/num_file_upload_processes 1
```

Comment: This workaround fixed the issue for me but right now, the possibly best solution would be to simply update the SDK by running: `$ gcloud components update`.